# Blank chars when printing array content

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, dos

I have a problem with writing content of my array. In the code below i try to print it on screen. But when the amount of arguments is small i don't always see all content. Sometime the are blanks in places of first n arguments. But when there are more arguments all 32 are showed. (array is 128 bytes)

```
mov     ax,32
mov     cx,ax
xor     si,si
pet:
    mov     dl,tablica[si]
    mov     ah,2h
    int     21h
    inc     si
loop pet
```

This is the declaration of array. Of course ds is iniialized by dane seg.

```
dane    segment
    tablica     db  128 dup('$')
dane    ends
```

Comment: Please add the code used to define `tablica`.

Comment: Done. But i don't think there is a problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a bug there. But on the other hand that's not the entire program.

You only print 32 bytes of your array that has size of 128 bytes. That does not help in debugging as you can't say which bytes of the array get printed. For debugging purposes I'd suggest you to replace `tablica db 128 dup('$')` with something that lets you know which bytes specifically get printed, for example:

```
tablica db 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

And then do you get `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF` as output? If not, then you probably corrupt your array somewhere else in your code before printing it, or your `ds` points to wrong place, or you have hooked or corrupted `int 21h` interrupt (this is very improbable if you're not handling interrupt vectors in your code).

Comment: DS is fine. After changing array to your everything works ok. I found out that i have a problem deeper inside me problem. Thanks for your help.